# CSS Adjacent Selector Issue

Tags: css, css-selectors

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="content_wide">
<div class="photo-center borderless"><img src="http://example.com/travel-path-map.png" alt="" title="" /></div>
```

...but for some reason I can't seem to target the photo-center div like this:

```
#content_wide + .photo-center { margin-top:10px }
```

Interestingly enough, a more general child selector works:

```
#content_wide > .photo-center { margin-top:10px }
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The div with the class `photo-center` is inside the div with the id `content_wide` so the child selector (`>`) works. The adjacent selector (`+`) would only work if they were next to each other, similar to this:

```
<div id="content_wide"><!-- content --></div>
<div class="photo-center borderless"><!-- more content --></iv>
```

Comment: ahhh! Yes. Brain is a little slow today. Any way to target photo-center only if it is the first descendant/child of content_wide?

Comment: `#content_wide .photo-center:first-child` should only target `.photo-center` if it's the first child

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `+` because `.photo-center` is not an adjacent sibling of `#content_wide`, it's a direct descendant (a child), so you can use the child selector `>`.

According to the Mozilla docs for [adjacent sibling selectors](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors):

> The + combinator separates two
>   selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is immediately
>   following the first.

The [child selector documentation](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Child_selectors) says:

> The > combinator separates two
>   selectors and matches the second
>   element only if it is a direct child
>   of the first.

Here is a jsFiddle demo of the above selectors, http://jsfiddle.net/YcHKm/1/

Comment: @Brent that happens a lot around here, people beat me by seconds all the time ;)

Comment: These basic questions are kind of a speed contest, huh.

Answer (score 2):

In your posted code, `.photo-center` is a child of `#content_wide`, not a sibling.

The `+` is a sibling selector and the `>` is a child selector.

The sibling selector isn't working because the elements aren't siblings.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `.photo-center` **isn't adjacent** to `content_wide`. It is a child of `content_wide`.

Here is an example of adjacent tags:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<h2>Test</h2>
```

In this example, h2 is adjacent to h1. This way, the `+` selector should work.